# ⌘+↑/↓ for Page Up/Down not working any more in Yosemite

Tags: keyboard, macos, shortcut

In Mavericks I could use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> for Page Up/Down but it's not working anymore. I googled it and some people said it's <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> but thats also not working. How can I fix that?

Comment: I just tested this on Yosemite and it is working for me. Do you have any keyboard shortcuts set which may override this? (System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts) Is there a specific program where you're having a problem?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just figgured it's a [Firefox](http://www.erfahrungen.com/mit/Firefox/) Plugin that caused this problem. Fixed now :)